# How to remove percentage of total from Google Analytics custom reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My company is attempting to send scheduled custom referral traffic reports to some of our affiliates and we would very much like to hide/remove the "% of total" values that are appended below visits and transactions so that our affiliates don't have to know what our total site visits and transactions are.

The totals aren't included in the Excel versions of the reports, but we want to use PDFs.

Comment: Just "Export to spreadsheet" solved my problem! I was copying and pasting like a dork and about to start processing the data like a nerd. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your Google Analytics page you will find `Customization` you can create a custom report for this.

Under type:  pick `Flat table` it wont display totals.

If you click on the link below you should be able to import the dummy report into your Google Analytics and see what I have done.  If you try and save this report as PDF you wont see Totals. This is a simple example just using Referral path and visits.   You can add filters to it as well so that you are only sending the information you want to the different affiliates.

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=z27OTlCjTvqsarRmJpFc4g